# Keep track of when and who, without using additional columns

Tags: database, t-sql, ssms

I don't know if this is common, but in my company, we have certain "standard" columns that we need to include in every table:

1. CreationDate: when the row was created
2. CreationUserId: who created the row
3. ModificationDate: when the row was last modified
4. ModificationUserId: who modified the row last

I want to know if there is a better way to keep track of these things without "bloating" up every table with these columns. One idea I had was to separate these columns into one global table that every table can make use of.

Comment: Is the 'bloating' you mention actually causing any issues?  Adding some version of those columns is a very widely used practice and provides a lot of value in other data processes such as reporting or auditing

Comment: Sure you can have an audit table.  It is now going to take more space as you will have key to the table name.   No less bloat.  That table will have a lot of traffic.   Users will have to join to that table.   Don't you have a script to create the standard columns?

Comment: If you put them on one global table as you thought of, you would have a huge table having a row for **every** row on **every** table on your database. How useful would that be?

Comment: @iamdave Not at the moment, no. I just wasn't sure if the way we do it is a common way to do it, as we're just a small company at the moment, so I was wondering if there were any better ways of doing it.

Comment: @noClue  In that case you do not have a problem.  As myself and others have stated this is a very normal practice and the 'cost' of having these columns kept up to date on each table is vastly outweighed by the benefits, especially further down the line.

Comment: @iamdave Well then, I guess I made a mountain out of a molehill. You, or anyone else, feel free to add an answer and I'll accept that. Would feel wrong if I posted my own answer and took points away from others. :P